# RoutePrefix not recognized in System.Web.Http 4.0 version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

**Actual Problem** : I have my backend `webapi`(`MVC 4`) controller named as XYZController, the consuming platforms are calling this `webapi` as X-Y-Z. I have to map this call to XYZ Controller.

To solve this I am trying to use `RoutePrefix`.

**Intermediate Problem** : RoutePrefix is not getting recognized as my `System.Web.Http` is of Version 4.0 and it is not part of this Version.

**Question** :

1. How do I upgrade my Version to 5? As this Version 5 provides
   RoutePrefix.
2. Is there any other way of fixing the Actual Problem?